# How to erase rows with combined criteria?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

How to erase rows of a table with two of criteria of two columns, combined? For example, I want to erase rows of products that come from France (country column) AND got the word ''wood'' in their name (name column).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Add column, custom column with formula

```
= if [Country]="France" and [Name]="Wood" then 1 else 0
```

Then use filter drop down atop that new column to uncheck the selection for [ ] 1 while leaving [x] 0

Potentially you meant that the Name field would contain the letters **wood** within a larger string of text (like Woodland), so you could use instead

```
= if [Country]="France" and Text.Contains(Text.Lower([Name]),"wood") then 1 else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Table.SelectRows` method:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table10"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,
        {{"Country", type text}, {"Name", type text}, {"Value", type text}}),
 
    filtered = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", 
        each not ([Country]="France" and Text.Contains([Name],"Wood",Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
in
    filtered
```

[image]